# Kafka Stream Confluent : Can't sink BigTable Connector. Unexpected error occurred with connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb, google-cloud-bigtable

I would like to sink the topic to Bigtable in GCP. But, I can't build the BigTable connector successfully. But, with the same topic, I can build the big query connector success.

BigTable Connector Error:
***Unexpected error occurred with  connector. Confluent connect

team is looking at your failure. We will reach out  if we need  more details. Please check  back here for an update.***

Additional Detail.
BigTable Config

Topic Name: page_events_agg
Input Kafka record value format: JSON
Input Kafka record key format: JSON

Query when I create the topic.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  page_events_agg_table
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='page_events_agg_table',KEY_FORMAT='JSON', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=1) 
AS
SELECT 
  SPLIT(DETAIL,'__')[2] ROW_KEY
, AS_VALUE(SPLIT(DETAIL,'__')[2]) PAGE
, sum(total_spending/1000/60) TOTAL_TIME_SPENDING_M
FROM customer_page_spending_stream
WINDOW TUMBLING ( SIZE 5 MINUTES ) 
GROUP BY SPLIT(detail,'__')[2]
EMIT CHANGES;
```

Another experiment. If I remove the key format when creating the topic. I got the Key Format Type with KAFKA. I can build the Bigtable connector pass, but I got the message in DLQ instead. It shows this error.

"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error

Comment: Please show example records in the topic without ksql (is the data actually JSON)? Did you mean to create connector on `page_events_agg_table` topic?